# How to make ui-grid column header keyboard navigatable?

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, angular-ui-grid, uiaccessibility

For doing some accessibility issues, I need the ui-grid column headers to be keyboard navigatable.

Comment: Can we have more info about your requirement ? What do you mean by navigable ? Where to navigate ?

Comment: I mean doing keyboard navigation like pressing tab key.

Comment: It's working by default no ? What is the problem on your side ?

Comment: It is not working by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is working by default.You just need to click the `first header` by using `mouse` and after that you can use the `Tab key` to navigate.Please see the video.

[**Tab navigation**](https://youtu.be/-30HWnI-Lck)

Comment: Even if it works as you said, but if the column is sortable; pressing space or enter is not working.

Comment: After focusing on the column header(by pressing Tab keys), if the column is sortable; it should sort the column by pressing enter or space, but it is not working.

Comment: Have you enabled `enableFiltering: true`, on your grid ?